# Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! on join + get() even setting xdebug

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error

When i run this code , it throws me an error

```
$result = Commission::leftJoin("bill" , "bill.id" , "=" , "Commissions.bill_id")->selectRaw(  $raw )->groupBy("Commissions.id")->get();
```

but this second code works fine

```
$result = Commission::leftJoin("bill" , "bill.id" , "=" , "Commissions.bill_id")->selectRaw(  $raw )->groupBy("Commissions.id")->get()->first();
```

even i put `->take(10)` , still throws me an error of

> Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!

as you can see on the error message , i have set the xdebug.max_nesting_level to 1000

now that being said, i need to get all bill with same Commission ID , but the `get()` function wont allow me to do so unless i put `first()`.  I am wondering what else may cause this error? Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have figured it out. Thanks for helping me sorting out possible causes . Anyway, I have to explain what was happened. The above code has nothing to do about the error(Apologies , I wasn't investigating enough and have to ask here).

I have Controller.php

```
public function retrieve( $type , $str = '' ){
    $base = new BaseReport();
    $class = ($type == "BaseReport" ? "Reports\\" . $type : "Reports\\" . $base->getMap($type) ) ;
    $report = new  $class();
    return $report->getVariable($str);
}

public function retrieveData($items , $type , $where , $groupby)
{
    $base = new BaseReport();
    $class = ($type == "BaseReport" ? "Reports\\" . $type : "Reports\\" . $base->getMap($type) ) ;
    $report = new  $class();
    return $report->retrieveData($items , $where , $groupby);
}
```

And a BaseReport.php

```
public function retrieveData($items , $where , $groupby = '' ){
    //SOME LONG CODE

//THIS IS THE CODE I STATED IN THE QUESTION
$result = $model->leftJoin($table , $table . "." $pk , "=" , $base_table . "." . $fk)
->selectRaw(  $raw )
->groupBy($base_table . "." . $pk)
->get();
return $result;}
```

Which I used consecutively somewhere in my page

```
$base_ = "commissions"
                        $transactions = $print_format->retrieveData($fcs , $base_ . ".report" , $where , $table_group_by );
                        $cellItem =  $print_format->retrieve( $base . ".report" , $fcs[$i]);
```

And the `$print_format->retrieve` is returning null and caused the error

Thanks Again for sorting out things.

Comment: So, what's your question ?

Comment: these two pieces of code are the same

Comment: No they aren't @limonte in the second example he uses `->first();`

Comment: @Daan oh, I see now, thx. You should use `->first()` without `->get()`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the query throwing an error? It seems you have an endless loop somewhere in the code connected to the query.

Comment: I have edited the post, i need to use get()

Comment: @lesssugar Thanks, i have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because one of the chained methods you're calling is calling itself,causing a loop and the failure message you are receiving.

My hunch is it is the selectRaw method. What SQL are you passing in?

In addition it looks like you could use eager loading rather than a join to achieve the end you seek.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

So Commission::with('bill')->where... or something similar.